# How to search & connect Miracast sink in my Android APP?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, wifi

I want to search and connect Miracast sink in my Android app.

I plan to do this like the Settings app. I download the android source code, find the \packages\apps\Settings\src\com\android\settings\wfd\WifiDisplaySettings.java

But at the beginning, Eclipse show can't import 2 packages:

```
import android.hardware.display.WifiDisplay;
import android.hardware.display.WifiDisplayStatus;
```

So, what's the problem? How can I import the 2 packages? Or is there any other implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I have knew that those packages are used in PDK.

they cant be used in application level.

So you should compile your project with entire AOSP source.